# Why the parentPid is 0x1 in my test code?

Tags: pointers, process

I want use pointer to get the pid of parent process with child process of it:

```
int main(void){
  pid_t childPid,*parentPid,pid;
  childPid = fork();
  if(childPid == 0 ){
    printf("[Child] the parent pid is 0x%u\n", *parentPid);
  }else if(childPid < 0){
    printf("there is something wrong");
  }else{
    pid = getpid();
    printf("[Parent] the pid is 0x%u\n",pid);
    parentPid = &pid;
  }
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

the output is:

```
[Parent] the pid is 0x5756
[Child] the parent pid is 0x1
```

there must be something wrong with my code, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child never modifies `*parentPid`, so it just contains random garbage. If you want your parent PID, call `getppid`.

Even if you fixed the race condition, the code still wouldn't work. Changing memory in the parent doesn't change that memory in the child unless the memory is shared. If all memory were shared by default, the child and parent would instantly obliterate each other's data and cause total chaos.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, it make sense to me now, so the *parentPid also have 2 copy in each process, modify the *parent in parent process, doesn't nothing to do with *parent process, so that the *parent in child output wrong value. Am I right? and +1 for point out the `getppid` function

Comment: @yozloy: Yes, that's correct. The child and parent actually share their memory, but through OS magic, they act as if they don't share their memory. (Through a feature called [copy on write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write).) This gives the best of both worlds -- you don't have two copies of everything, but the parent and child don't obliterate each other. (Imagine if an object was freed in the child and that memory re-allocated. That would corrupt the parent hopelessly.)

Comment: That's really some magic out there, for now I just stick to my way, I'm gonna read the `copy on write ` later, because for a noob like me, it start to get crazy about the magic